# Draggable marker from google maps v3 in fancybox 2.1.3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, draggable, google-maps-markers, fancybox-2

i have a problem with a draggable marker from google maps who is shown in a fancybox.
"draggable: false" works fine, if i chance it to "true" it´s no more working.

i have google maps api v3 and fancybox 2.1.3

example: http://www.lenticularis.net/fancyboxtest/google-maps-and-fancybox.php

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

a map requires a `center`-option, but in `myOptions` you provide a `position`-option.